# Equivalence of NP-complete problems

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, np-complete

I am currently studying the concept of NP - complete, and I came across a question that I'm not sure about my own answer (currently, it's a "Yes."). The question is: assuming Problem A requires finding a a maximum number of people. I was able to show that Problem A's answer is equivalent to the cardinality of the **maximum** independent set of an **undirected** graph $G$. Now, as we know that finding a **maximum** independent set of an undirected graph is **NP-hard**, does it imply Problem A must also be NP-hard, which means A is NP-complete?

Comment: There's a distinction to be drawn between *decision problems* (yes-no answers) and computational problems.  Review the definitions of NP-hard and NP-complete.

Comment: @hardmath: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Can you kindly let me know if my argument below is true?

 First, due to the nature of Problem A, it can always be reduced, in polynomial time, to the problem finding the maximum independent set. So it is sufficient to show Problem A is NP-complete if we can show Problem A is in NP. But given a candidate of the solution to Problem A, it is the matter of verifying if that solution is a maximum independent set in a certain graph. Now, verifying if a set is a maximal independent set can be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: To verify if a maximal independent set is actually a maximum independent set, I don't think there is a polynomial-time algorithm to do that. So can we conclude that Problem A is not in NP?

Answer (score 1):

(In all cases below, by "reduction" I mean "polynomial-time reduction.")

To prove NP-hardness you must show a reduction from an NP-hard problem to your problem.  You have a reduction from your problem to an NP-hard problem (indeed a  [parsimonious reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsimonious_reduction) from your problem to a [#P-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP-complete) problem) but that is insufficient to show NP-hardness or #P-completeness.  If you don't have a proof of NP-hardness, you don't have a proof of NP-completeness either.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can show the problem of finding the maximum independent set is *exactly the same* as Problem A. Is that enough to conclude Problem A is NP-complete?